# Control my Droid from Windows

Tags: windows-7, android

Looking to use a full-sized keyboard/mouse as much as I can - will make setting up/initial config much easier.

I see a number of 'control Windows from your Droid' apps. looking to go the other way.

Comment: What functions specifically do you want to control? Or just the entire phone? Both Webs and Angela provided answers going both directions and neither are marked correct (and no comments from you) so I think you should specify what exactly you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

Is there an SSH program for the Droid? If so I would think between that and VNC you should have what you need.

For example, on my jailbroke iPod I installed SSH client on the iPod. Once SSH is enabled I can use a VNC viewer to connect to the iPod over SSH. If there isn't an app to download for the droid that enables SSH, you might have to look into rooting it to get that functionality.